# Google maps native Ionic v4 - Not show on Android

Tags: google-maps, ionic4, ionic-native

I can not see the map on an Android device.

I have created the necessary API for the Android SDK and I followed the steps indicated in a Stackoverflow post:

https://ionic.tutorials24x7.com/blog/implement-google-maps-in-ionic-4-for-android

But I have not gotten it to work either and it does not give me any kind of error.

loadMap() {

```
this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {

  camera: {

    target: {

      lat: 43.0741704,
      lng: -89.3809802
    },

    zoom: 18,
    tilt: 30

  }

});
```

}

async onButtonClick() {

```
this.map.clear();

this.map.getMyLocation().then((location: MyLocation) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null ,2));

  // Move the map camera to the location with animation
  this.map.animateCamera({
    target: location.latLng,
    zoom: 17,
    tilt: 30
  });

  // add a marker
  let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
    title: '@ionic-native/google-maps plugin!',
    snippet: 'This plugin is awesome!',
    position: location.latLng,
    animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.BOUNCE
  });

  // show the infoWindow
  marker.showInfoWindow();

  // If clicked it, display the alert
  marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
    this._defaultService.mostrar_toast('clicked!', 2000);
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  this._defaultService.mostrar_toast(err.error_message, 2000);
});
```

}

How to run 'ionic cordova run browser' if you see a map, I imagine it may be a problem with the API, but I do not know what it can be.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. The 'ion-content had a class with these properties:

```
.container{
   background-color: #eee;
   background-image: url ('../ assets / imgs / fondo.jpg');
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

When I remove that class, it worked, although I do not understand exactly why